# How to run my Django application automatically on production server

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I built an application on my local machine with Python and Django. Its working fine. Now, I would like to automate the process to start my Django application on a production server.

What I have to do to achieve that?

Comment: Here are some links which will help you understand how you can deploy your Django project - [Link1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/), [Link2](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12.html), [Link3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-local-django-app-to-a-vps).

Comment: The docs for runserver has a big sign saying don't use it for production...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Django documentation don't recommend to use Django built-in server on production.**

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone
>   through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s
>   gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web
>   servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production
>   environment is outside the scope of Django.)

It's recommended to use [gunicorn](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.3/) or [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#) to launch your WSGI application :
- [How to use Django with gunicorn](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/)
- [How to use Django with uWSGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/)

Another good practice, it's to use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org) to start your process, **Then if it dies or get killed for some reason, supervisord will restart this process**.

And to finish, use **[nginx](https://www.nginx.com)** or **[apache](http://www.apache.org)** as proxy server, which are strong server that can handle the charge. Most of tutorials or documentations, recommend to use nginx because it's a high-performance HTTP server.

> NGINX is a free, open-source, high-performance HTTP server and reverse
>   proxy, as well as an IMAP/POP3 proxy server. NGINX is known for its
>   high performance, stability, rich feature set, simple configuration,
>   and low resource consumption.

Check this to know how to configure them :
- [Deploying Gunicorn with nginx](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.3/deploy.html)
- [Deploying uWSGI with nginx](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)

Also before deploy your Django app, read this checklist, to make sure everything is well configured  : [Django - Deployment checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/#deployment-checklist)

With this architecture and tools, you will be able to launch your gunicorn process with a simple `supervisord` command. That's all. Then gunicorn will launch your WSGI application.