# Running standalone Django runserver

Tags: python, django, linux

I have set up a VPS and installed Django on it.
I've installed Django within the virtual environment i created using `python3 -m venv env` and activated via `source env/bin/activate`.

In order to run the Django built-in webserver i need to run `python3 manage.py runserver`.

The webserver runs until i close the SSH session, so how can i run a standalone webserver without being dependent on the SSH session. (And also taking advantage of being ran inside the virtual environment)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run my Django application automatically on production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930640/how-to-run-my-django-application-automatically-on-production-server)

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way to do this is use docker.
Example how to setup docker with django:
https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/

Or you can solve this with screen in linux system, but remember this is not for production use:
https://linuxhint.com/screen_command_ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Running it as a background process is a quick solution.

```
nohup python3 manage.py runserver &
```

If you really want to take it to next level then consider running it using one of the Django deployment options which are very well documented by Django team.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/

I have used Gunicorn with nginx server running to front it so that nginx can server static content. you can find details here.

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#using-virtualenv